# how to show data in mysql depending to a user who logged in mysql and codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how to limit the user can only CRUD his own data in a table. for example there are 2 users, namely user1 and user2 in table_user, each user has data in table_transaction. When user1 logs in, the data displayed is only data belonging to user1

Comment: another example , stackoverflow save user question in table_question , When a user logs in, the displayed question list is his own, he can CRUD it

Comment: Most of the cases this restriction is not done on the database level, but on the application level as most applications would use a single database user to connect to the database.